# Update to visual studio also updated .csproj and .sln files. Should I check in both these changed files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, updates, csproj, sln-file

changes to .csproj as below.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>React</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind />
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptOutFile />
    <TypeScriptOutDir />
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot />
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
  </PropertyGroup>
```

2) changes to sln file as below

> Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
>       Visual Studio Version **16**
>       VisualStudioVersion = **16.0.30011.22**
>       MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
>       Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "PlantSight-Portal", "PlantSight-Portal.csproj",
>   "{BF5F832B-57F4-454F-B858-2CB5CBA60B95}"
>       EndProject
>       Project("{**9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556**}") = "PlantSight-Portal.UnitTests",
>   "Tests\PlantSight-Portal.UnitTests\PlantSight-Portal.UnitTests.csproj",
>   "{C5B22C88-3FCF-4EF7-B0B8-CD191994A397}"
>       EndProject

Comment: If other developer are going to use previous version then NO, it will break the project on their system.

Comment: Over the last few versions of VS solutions have round tripped (assuming the projects can load), so for the `.sln` you can check it in (the version seems to get updated on any change, the project ids change from time to time for some reason).

Comment: What about the changes that got added to .csproj @Richard?

Comment: I can't work out what has changed ... or are you suggesting the whole thing is added? (Ultimately there is nothing like just trying it).